# AngularJS - Animate does not work when compiling, nh-show/ng-hide yes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, angularjs-directive

Everything works fine, it compiles fine, runs the model and controller, ng-show/ng-hide works well, but the animations are not integrating, how can I fix it?

Please check my example:

```
var html = ''
+'<input type="checkbox" ng-model="isPlay" />Show/Hide'
+'<br /><p class="animate-show" ng-show="isPlay">Hello {{name1}}</p>';
angular.element(document.body).html(html);
MyCompiler(angular.element(document.body));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nng2r22r/2/

Thank you very much.